# Error when creating a Jasper file from database

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a multi module project where it read a byte array column from database and create a jasper file to sent it to email.

From my web application it works perfectly, but when running from my Java SE application I'm getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error loading object from file : D:\file.jasper
    at com.project.RReportJasper.gerarJasperPrint(RReportJasper.java:78)
    at com.project.RReportJasper.gerarJasperPrint(RReportJasper.java:53)
    at com.project.RReportJasper.geraRelatorioPDF(RReportJasper.java:29)
    at com.project.RGenerate.geraRelatorio(RGenerate.java:63)
    at com.project.AbstractUtil.gerar(AbstractUtil.java:44)
    at com.project.util.Util.gerar(DameUtil.java:66)
    at com.project.mail.EnvioEmailAbstractBase.montarAnexo(EnvioEmailAbstractBase.java:514)
    ... 16 more
```

The weird is when reading from my web application, the return of bytes from database is **120323** bytes and when the Java SE application read this, the size is **240645** (double size)

Here is my entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "arquivo")
public class EArquivo  extends TransferObject<Long> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -183345111110383391L;

    private byte[] arquivo;
    private String nome;

    @Override
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "arquivo_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "arquivo_id_seq", allocationSize = 1, sequenceName = "arquivo_id_seq")
    @Column(name = "id_arquivo")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }   

    @Column (name = "arquivo")
    public byte[] getArquivo() {
        return arquivo;
    }

    public void setArquivo(byte[] arquivo) {
        this.arquivo = arquivo;     
    }

    @Column(length=80)
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    @Transient
    public File getFile() throws NotFoundException {
        File file = null;
        try {
            if(arquivo == null){
                return null;
            }
            byte[] bytes = arquivo;
            if (bytes.length == 0) {
                throw new NotFoundException("Not found for: " + getFilial().getCnpj());
            }
            String cnpj = getFilial().getCnpj();

            file = Arquivo.createTempFile("file-" + cnpj + "-", ".jasper");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(bytes);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            FileCleaner.track(file, file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return file;
    }
}
```

Someone have any idea of what might be this problem?

**EDIT**: Add how I get the file in my bean

Comment: You don't say how you get the data from the database to the file, but my guess is that you have a character encoding problem - the fact that the file size is twice the size of what you get from the database leads me to suspect that you're getting ascii (single-byte) characters from the database, and are writing it out with a double-width encoding (perhaps unicode?).

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek I tried it but the problem still happening. Anyway, I found the solution posted below. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the Postgres jar.

In my web container the version is 9.1 and in my Java SE Application is 8.4.
When I update my app to use 9.1 the problem was solved.